# Pip SSLError malloc failure in chroot

Tags: pip, openssl, qemu, arm64, chroot

I have mounted a debian (linaro) based `rootfs.img.raw` created from sparse image (with `simg2img`) and ran chroot:

```
$ sudo chroot /mnt/intrinsycimg qemu-aarch64-static /bin/bash
```

using qemu to emulate ARM64. My `qemu-aarch64` version is 2.11.1(Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.26).

Using pip (version 18.1) on python (version 3.7.3) I tried to install a random package with it, but I get the following error:

```
root@user:/home/linaro# pip3 install --user progress
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
Collecting progress
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement progress (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for progress
```

I tried adding a `--trusted-host` flag as per this [github issue answer](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5448#issuecomment-394254705) and I got a malloc failure:

```
root@user:/home/linaro# pip3 install progress --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
Collecting progress
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))': /simple/progress/
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/progress/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/progress/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336236609, '[SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement progress (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for progress
```

I also tried to mount `/run`, `/dev`, `/sys` and `/proc` (e.g `sudo mount --rbind /run/ /mnt/linaroimg/run/`) as [this user suggested](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5448#issuecomment-484987092), but I get the same result.

My openssl version is `OpenSSL 1.1.1d` and I found an issue regarding [malloc failure for 1.1.1d](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/10015#issue-498314372), so if I run the same command I get the same error:

```
root@user:/home/linaro# python3 -c 'import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlopen("https://pypi.org")'
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 278
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1285, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, **http_conn_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1383, in __init__
    context = ssl._create_default_https_context()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 565, in create_default_context
    context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 388, in __new__
    self = _SSLContext.__new__(cls, protocol)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] malloc failure (_ssl.c:2994)
```

I tried manually compiling `OpenSSL_1_1_1g` version:

```
root@user:/home/linaro# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019)
```

but same end result. I'm suspicious of `Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d`, but I git cloned the openssl repo and checked out the `OpenSSL_1.1.1g` tag. Also I would like to avoid compiling the openssl myself, since I prefer to update it via apt later on.

Any ideas how I should fix this issue?

Comment: What QEMU version are you using?

Comment: @PeterMaydell It's `qemu-aarch64 version 2.11.1(Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.26)`

Comment: That is an ancient QEMU version which has a lot of known bugs in its linux-user-mode support (some of which are known to cause this kind of failure). Try again with the most recent version.

Comment: Sorry for a late answer, had troubles compiling qemu-5.0.0. But yes, you were right, this fixed the issue. Can you change this to an answer since most people will probably install `qemu-user-static` via apt (with outdated version) and can get the same error?

Comment: Sure. Could you update the question text to include the qemu version too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using an old version of QEMU, which has known bugs in its linux-user mode support (it has in particular problems with multithreaded guest programs). Trying a more recent version such as QEMU 5.0 should cause the errors to go away.